# text comparison/difference algorithm

Tags: c#, comparison, diff

Is there a c# library/algorithm that compares 2 texts and displays what is different in them?

Answer (score 3):

See [Diff.Net](http://www.menees.com/index.html):

> Diff.NET is a differencing utility I
>   wrote in C#.  It provides side-by-side
>   differencing for files and
>   directories.  For files it also
>   provides an overview diff and a
>   line-to-line diff.  And it can do a
>   visual difference of binary files.