# Is there a .NET text diff library from Microsoft?

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, diff

I would like to use a C# .NET diff/comparison library for text files (C++ to be more precise, but it should not matter).

I have found a lot of libraries in the topic but what I need is a something that is part of the .NET library or it comes from Microsoft. The reason of this restriction is that I do not have to go over our company's long open source tool approval process.

Does C# .NET has such feature?

An example for the usage: I have two slightly different `.cpp` files. I have to create one `.cpp` file which will have a `#ifdef` according to the differences of the two files and we can use one file at two places controlled by a predecessor definition.

Comment: While text diffing is actually a fairly difficult problem, algorithms exist that can be translated into C#. No such functionality already exists in .net.

Comment: Not from Ms but a fine piece of software:[See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887238/how-to-compare-two-rich-text-box-contents-and-highlight-the-characters-that-are/24970638?s=1|0.2751#24970638)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such built in functionality in any Microsoft .Net library.