# Is there a more efficient approach to this diff-like function?

Tags: c#, .net, diff

I have a C# function that compares two strings `oldString` and `newString` line-by-line. Each comparison takes case into account only within quotes. For example, these two lines are equal:

```
If Foo Then: Debug.Print "Hello World!"
If foo Then: Debug.print "Hello World!"
```

And these two are unequal:

```
If Foo Then: Debug.Print "Hello World!"
If Foo Then: Debug.Print "hello world!"
```

The function returns a new file constructed from `newString`, but wherever there are unchanged lines, the lines from `oldString` are used instead. So if this is `oldString`:

```
If Foo Then
    Debug.Print "Hello World!"
End If
Debug.Print "This line will be deleted soon."
```

And this is `newString`:

```
If foo Then
    Debug.print "Hello World!"
    Debug.print "This is a new line."
End If
```

Then the function returns this:

```
If Foo Then
    Debug.Print "Hello World!"
    Debug.print "This is a new line."
End If
```

Currently I'm using this code based on the dynamic programming approach to the longest common substring problem, with some simple optimizations:

```
public static string FixCase(string oldString, string newString) {
    if (string.Equals(oldString, newString, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)) {
        return newString;
    }

    var oldLines = oldString.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
    var newLines = newString.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

    var headEqualLines = new List<string>();
    var minLineCount = oldLines.Count < newLines.Count ? oldLines.Count : newLines.Count;
    for (var i = 0; i < minLineCount; i++) {
        if (VbaLineEqual(oldLines[i], newLines[i])) {
            headEqualLines.Add(oldLines[i]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    oldLines.RemoveRange(0, headEqualLines.Count);
    newLines.RemoveRange(0, headEqualLines.Count);
    minLineCount -= headEqualLines.Count;
    var tailEqualLines = new List<string>();
    if (oldLines.Count > 0 && newLines.Count > 0) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= minLineCount; i++) {
            if (VbaLineEqual(oldLines[oldLines.Count - i], newLines[newLines.Count - i])) {
                tailEqualLines.Add(oldLines[oldLines.Count - i]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        tailEqualLines.Reverse();
        oldLines.RemoveRange(oldLines.Count - tailEqualLines.Count - 1, tailEqualLines.Count);
        newLines.RemoveRange(newLines.Count - tailEqualLines.Count - 1, tailEqualLines.Count);
    }

    var lengths = new int[oldLines.Count + 1, newLines.Count + 1];
    for (var i = 0; i < oldLines.Count; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < newLines.Count; j++) {
            if (VbaLineEqual(oldLines[i], newLines[j]))
                lengths[i + 1, j + 1] = lengths[i, j] + 1;
            else
                lengths[i + 1, j + 1] = lengths[i + 1, j] > lengths[i, j + 1] ? lengths[i + 1, j] : lengths[i, j + 1];
        }
    }
    var result = new List<string>();
    var x = oldLines.Count;
    var y = newLines.Count;
    while (x != 0 && y != 0) {
        if (lengths[x, y] == lengths[x - 1, y]) {
            x--;
        } else if (lengths[x, y] == lengths[x, y - 1]) {
            result.Add(newLines[y - 1]);
            y--;
        } else {
            result.Add(oldLines[x - 1]);
            x--;
            y--;
        }
    }
    while (y != 0) {
        result.Add(newLines[y - 1]);
        y--;
    }
    result.Reverse();
    return string.Join("\r\n", headEqualLines.Concat(result).Concat(tailEqualLines));
}

static bool VbaLineEqual(string oldLine, string newLine) {
    if (string.Equals(oldLine, newLine, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        return true;
    if (!string.Equals(oldLine, newLine, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        return false;
    var quoting = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < oldLine.Length; i++) {
        if (quoting && oldLine[i] != newLine[i])
            return false;
        if (oldLine[i] == '"')
            quoting = !quoting;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when I run this against a pair of strings with 5,000 or so lines and changes near the beginning and end, performance and memory usage are both pretty dreadful, probably due to allocating an array of 5,000 × 5,000 `int`.

Is there any pre-built library that can handle this comparison, or a more efficient algorithm I can use? Note that I'd like to license my code under the zlib license, so GNU diffutils is no good.

Comment: Diff is no trivial task. [See here for an example!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887238/how-to-compare-two-rich-text-box-contents-and-highlight-the-characters-that-are/24970638?s=1|0.2755#24970638)

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Diff Match and Patch library](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) can solve this for you.

Comment: How do I specify the comparison function with this library?

Comment: The library is explained [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API). Basically, you download the library and use the appropriate language version module. For C# this means you have a single source file containing the class implementation. Using this you create a diff_match_patch object and call its diff_main(text1, text2). This will return  a list of Diff objects for the give texts. For C# there's also test code included.

Comment: I cannot see any overloads in the API that allow me to specify a comparison function.