# Count the characters changed in a string

Tags: c#

What I need to do seems simple enough but I can't seem to find a good way to do it. My app reads text off of a document but sometimes gets it wrong. Users are allowed to change the text in a verification step. What I need to know is how many characters changed, including case.

For example, 
Original value: i23 MAin St
Value changed to: 123 Main Street
The number of characters changed in this instance would be 6. I then need to capture this value in a variable for later use. Is there a good way to do this in c#?

Comment: What if the user inserts and deletes characters?

Comment: You're looking for Levenshtein Distance.

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein

Comment: _What I need to do seems simple enough_ No it isn't! At least if you allow deleting and inserting characters it is a really tough task with no exact solution!  For a solution for doing a _diff_ see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887238/how-to-compare-two-rich-text-box-contents-and-highlight-the-characters-that-are/24970638?s=1|0.2754#24970638)