# How to find the difference between 2 strings and replace the different things in the original string in C#

Tags: c#

So this is the example:

```
string one = "Test123";

string two = "123Test12345"
```

I want to compare the strings and replace it the characters by using indexes.
So the string "two" becomes string "one" with placing 123 in front of the Test123 and 45 behind the Test123.
Is there anyway to that?

Comment: If the end result is to reproduce the content of string `two`, why is `one = two;` (or vice versa) not an option?

Comment: If you are replacing all the different things, just assign string 2 to string 1

Comment: This is because multiple clients are working on one document and it needs to update otherwise the server has to send the whole document again and again

Comment: I have a nuget package for this, called difflib - https://www.nuget.org/packages/difflib/2017.7.26.1241 - you can use that to work out the differences, but it might not be optimal if your document gets really big in size.

Comment: `String.IndexOf` will find the starting index of the match. You know the length. Then it's a simple matter of playing with `string.SubString` and gluing things back together

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen i can only find things about ratio with that library and that isnt what i need right now

Comment: No, the library would be able to tell you exactly which bits were added, were deleted, modified, or stayed the same.

Comment: Doing a Diff is a non-trivial thing. Very hard unless you can add limiting conditions and rules! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887238/how-to-compare-two-rich-text-box-contents-and-highlight-the-characters-that-are/24970638?s=1|27.1951#24970638) for a discouraging example

Comment: Here is an example with Difflib, code and output: https://gist.github.com/lassevk/caba9a5009871bc57723660e4ff5c5d4

Answer (score -1):

## You can compare simply by using Regular expression

```
string outputText = Regex.Match(two, one,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
Console.WriteLine(outputText) // "Test123"
```

Comment: Careful about the stringcase , dont there is third parameter where you can find multiple choice,,, the above code work for me