# C# compare 2 txt files and find differences

Tags: c#

I need to compare 2 text files and save the differences in another file.

**File 1**

```
aaa

bbb

ccc
```

**File 2**

```
aaa

eee

ccc

ccc
```

I'm currently using this code:

```
String directory = @"C:\Users\confronto.txt";
String[] linesA = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, @"C:\Users\pari.txt"));
String[] linesB = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, @"C:\Users\dispari.txt"));

IEnumerable<String> onlyB = linesB.Except(linesA);
```

but this code doesn't see the double `ccc` as a difference, so the `confronto.txt` is:

```
eee
```

instead of:

```
eee

ccc
```

as it should be.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Or you can just scan the lines after and add the duplicates yourself. Something like if (line(i + 1) == line(i)) onlyB.add(line(i))

Comment: DIFF is HARD - Depending on the details of your requirements this may be well beyond any simple solution. For a sobering example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887238/how-to-compare-two-rich-text-box-contents-and-highlight-the-characters-that-are/24970638?r=SearchResults&s=1|27.1920#24970638)

Comment: Why is `bbb`not included in the diff? its only included in the first file.

Comment: Try to express the exact rules of what you're trying to achieve. There's a good chance that after that, you'll be able to do it. At least it would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any logic behind why you want that duplicate value. You can try combining both the array and group the result set by string element and take only those where count is either 1 or greater than 2. Something like

```
public static void Main()
{
   string[] file1 = new string[]{"aaa","bbb","ccc"};
   string[] file2 = new string[]{"aaa","bbb","ccc","eee","ccc"};

    List<string> file = new List<string>(file1);
    file.AddRange(file2);

    var data = file.GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => new {Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
    .Where(y => y.Count == 1 || y.Count > 2)
    .Select(x => x.Key);

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Which results in

```
ccc 
eee
```